# Array confusion with find and includes

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Given the following arrays:

```
const x = [2, 14, 54, 109, 129, 136, 165, 312, 320, 330, 335, 348, 399, 440, 450, 461, 482, 501, 546, 547, 549, 559, 582, 584, 615, 620, 647, 682];
const y = [539, 681, 682, 683];
```

Using node v 7.3.0 I observe the following unexpected behavior:

```
[> x.find(y.includes, y);
undefined
[> y.find(x.includes, x);
682
```

Sample Snippet:

```js
const x = [2, 14, 54, 109, 129, 136, 165, 312, 320, 330, 335, 348, 399, 440, 450, 461, 482, 501, 546, 547, 549, 559, 582, 584, 615, 620, 647, 682];
const y = [539, 681, 682, 683];

console.log(x.find(y.includes, y))
console.log(y.find(x.includes, x))
```

However code like `x.find(element => y.includes(element));` always finds the element as expected.

I don't get why the two calls that just use `find` and `includes` would ever yield different results and would be delighted if someone knows an explanation.

Comment: arguments are different for find() and includes().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason `x.find(y.includes, y);` is returning `undefined` is because of arguments passed in function.

Callback of `Array.find` expects 3 values viz., `item, index, array` and callback of `Array.includes` expects 2 arguments, viz., `item, fromIndex`.

Basically, your current index will be treated as `fromIndex` in `Array.includes` and will skip elements before it.

So after four iterations would look like, `Array.includes` will look for values after 4th element and `y` does not have them. Hence it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Wow. This was subtle to me. Thanks for the clarification!